# Azure file storage for configuration files needed for Azure hosted API

Tags: azure, filesystems, configuration-files

My project requires configuration files loaded. Is there a way to use the system.file.io in an Azure-hosted solution?

I'm pretty sure I can't find the answer because I'm not exactly sure how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Azure App Services to host your API.

You can configure your configuration information in the Azure portal see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

In development environments or for non security related configuration you can place it in the App.Config or appsettings.json.